# Google Sheets QUERY of discontinuous columns in order to import desired range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two google sheets in the same workbook and I am trying to import certain columns from one into the other sheet based on what hour of class was chosen. For example, I have the Date in column A, Name in B, Email in C, and Number in D and other stuff, then the Class in I.

Column A - Date
Column B - Name
Column C - Email
Column D - Number
...
Column I - Class

My goal is to import column B through D if column I has a certain class. I tried a using this if statemnt: `=if('Confirmação'!I2 = A1,(=importrange("sheet_url","Confirmação!B2:D2")), "NOPE")`
where A1 has the name of the class to look for, but it resulted in a #Error.

Then I tried a variety of query such as the following:
`=QUERY({'Confirmação'!B2:D2,'Confirmação'!I2},"Where I = 'Terça 19h English 1'")`
`=QUERY({'Confirmação'!B2:D2, 'Confirmação'!I2},"Where 'Confirmação'!I = 'Terça 19h English 1'")`

and also added the IfError: `=iferror(QUERY('Confirmação'!B4:I4,"Where I = 'Terça 19h English 1'"),"Vaga")`

Could someone correct my functions or help with a google script? Thank you! Very much appreciated! (Sorry about the Portugues-it's a project I am working on in Brazil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a QUERY, you can use the =FILTER() function to solve your problem. Doing the following:

```
=FILTER('OriginSheet'!B:D;'OriginSheet'!I:I = 'Certain Class')
```

Then you can still add more conditions:

```
=FILTER('OriginSheet'!B:D;'OriginSheet'!I:I = 'Class 1';'OriginSheet'!I:I = 'Class 2';'OriginSheet'!I:I = 'Class 3')
```

Try that and let me know if it worked.

Comment: What a lifesaver! Thank you! The first one worked like a charm. Not sure about the second but for my purposes, the first filter did exactly what I needed it to, thank you The only small change is to change the 'Certain Class' to "Certain Class". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to do it using `QUERY`:

Using your formula with slight modification:
`=QUERY({'Confirmação'!B2:D2,'Confirmação'!I2},"select * where Col3 = 'Terça 19h English 1'")`.

In case you want the formula to take the class name dynamically, then you can modify the formula to `=QUERY({'Confirmação'!B2:D2,'Confirmação'!I2},"select * where Col3 = '"&A1&"'")` where `A1` is the cell with the class name.

Comment: That does it as well with one modification, where the Col3 should be Col4. But other than that it works well! Thank you I appreciate you explaining the QUERY method! `=QUERY({'Confirmação'!B2:D2,'Confirmação'!I2},"select * where Col4 = '"&A1&"'")`

Comment: Yes, should be `Col4`. Sorry my bad.